# Scrollable large image in Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I am exploring the use of Compose (starting with Android, but with an idea to look into Multiplatform eventually), and trying to figure out how to implement a huge, scrollable/zoomable background bitmap with overlaid images/text.

In native, pre-Compose Android I usually used an approach similar to https://github.com/johnnylambada/WorldMap , which basically overrides the Canvas renderer and uses Android's ability to read portions of a bitmap (rather than the whole bitmap at once).

An alternative approach to this is to tile the image and join them seamlessly; one example of that approach I've seen so far is: https://github.com/p-lr/MapCompose

Are there other potentially useful libraries/online exampels that would be worth exploring?

Comment: https://github.com/saket/telephoto